# Pair Production via Black Hole

Tags: black-holes, pair-production

I think this should be a straight forward question. Is it possible for a photon to pass near a black hole and be turned into a matter and anti-matter pair according to current theory?

**Edit:**
From the comments I understand the above is thought to be possible, but extremely rare/unlikely. I didn't realize that the black hole may need to be charged though. Is it a requirement that the black hole be charged?

Comment: If the black hole were big enough, then its radius of curvature near the event horizon is sufficiently small to only provide weak corrections to the predictions of quantum field theory. In such cases, I presume this possible. Note however, that even in flat space-time the process you mention is not kinematically allowed, so all you can do is to produce a virtual pair which must then immediately (with some probability) annihilate back into a photon.

Comment: @Prahar Thanks, I am trying to understand but I find your comment enigmatic. If a virtual pair is thus created would it be the case that at least one of the two also must then immediately (with some probability) get sucked into the black hole?

Comment: You can't say "must" and then say "with some probability". Yes, there does exist a probability of one of the two pairs enters the black hole and the other escapes. This, in fact, leads to Hawking radiation.

Comment: @Prahar Maybe I have misunderstood something. When you write _"one of the two pairs"_, are you referring to 2*2=4 total particles?

Comment: The probability of such a process infinitesimally small, unless the black hole is microscopic. Most photons fall in or pass and that's that. It seems that Hawking himself got this pair production nonsense started, but there is very little in terms of physics that makes sense about it.

Comment: @CuriousOne Thanks, can you link to some papers that you find offer convincing arguments against the pair production idea?

Comment: @Livid: I am not a theoretician, but I have a hunch of how all of this mythology originated. Microscopic black hole have enormous gravitational fluctuations at their event horizon, with similar "forces" that one can semiclassically assign to a charged particle at distances at which pair production happens. Leave out the word "microscopic" and now all black holes seem to do the same, even when they don't. Take a look at surface gravity and tides at http://xaonon.dyndns.org/hawking/ and change the mass from 1 solar mass to e.g. a metric ton or so... the $M^2$ dependence makes all the difference.

Comment: What has the "black hole" to do with this? Pair production happens whenever there's a photon with enough energy and some charged object it can interact with to give the "excess" momentum to that ordinarily forbids pair production from a free photon.

Comment: That was bad english on my part. I meant, "one of the two particles in a pair". @CuriousOne - You are correct, the probability for this process to happen is incredibly small. This is why black holes do not immediately Hawking radiate after they are formed. There is a large separation between the formation and decay into stationarity (where the black hole can be treated classically) and when Hawking radiation starts. More precisely, the time for a black hole to evaporate due to Hawking radiation is $\frac{M^3}{\hbar}$

Comment: @ACuriousMind I am trying to understand whether matter can be created without any pre-existing matter (ie from radiation + BH)

Comment: @Prahar: Indeed, the concordance model for black holes makes them incredibly "boring" objects. That's the universe's version of watching paint dry. My hope would be that these models are wrong and that black holes show some measurable deviations from the predicted behavior. I wouldn't bet on that, but it would be seriously cool if the physics at the event horizon would be completely different from our semiclassical expectations.